# replace group by with reducebykey

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code in dataframe. I am using the following statement to perform group by and it is not performing well on big datasets.

```
npa = npa.groupby(f.col('phonecode').alias('npa')).agg(f.mean('latitude').alias('latitude'), f.mean('longitude').alias('longitude'))

NPA dataset:-
+---------+---------+-----------+------------+
|phonecode| latitude|  longitude|country     |
+---------+---------+-----------+------------+
|   425   |47.496384|-121.784424|          US|
|   360   |47.540962|  -122.6358|          US|
```

Please advise how I can use reducebykey to solve the performance issue.

Comment: I don't think using the RDD API will improve the performance. The code looks simple enough, and it might just be slow because of the amount of data involved.

Comment: please add details such as - data size, data format , sample data , cluster configuration & spark version and data storage layer info like s3 or azure blob storage.